# Why does method "combinations" return Iterator rather than Stream in Scala?

Tags: scala, stream, iterator, scala-collections, lazy-evaluation

I noticed that method `combinations` (from [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/collection/SeqLike.html)) returns `Iterator`. It looks reasonable that the method should be "lazy" to avoid generating all combinations in advance. Now I wonder, why it returns `Iterator` instead of `Stream` (which is a lazy list in Scala).

So, why does `combinations` return `Iterator` rather than `Stream` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `Stream` it is more likely that all generated values will be held in memory.

```
scala> val s = Stream.iterate(0)(_ + 1)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> s.drop(3).head
res1: Int = 3

scala> s
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, 1, 2, 3, ?)
```

When you retain a reference to your `Stream`, all generated elements will remain in memory. With an `Iterator` this is less likely to happen.

Of course this does not have to be the reason why the Scala library is designed the way it is...

Answer (score 4):

I think because Stream caches all previously returned elements, so you would end up with all of them in memory. Iterator only returns the next one

Answer (score 3):

As I can see on `CombinationsItr` code, you have a lazy evaluation each time you call `next` method.
See https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala#L198

So when using `next` to get the next combination like this for example :

```
scala> val combinations = "azertyuiop".combinations(2)
scala> combinations.next
res9: String = az
```

the result of `next` is evaluated lazily.

Comment: Does this mean you can drop from the iterator without creating the intermediate values?

Comment: That's an interesting question, as we can see on the `Iterator` code (https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L292), the `drop` method will return a new instance of `Iterator` that reference the previous one (where you call `drop`). This means that even the dropped version of `Iterator` will be evaluated lazily (but will contains it's self `remaining` counter).

Answer (score 3):

`Iterator` is cheaper than `Stream`. You can always get the latter from the former, if you need.